# Reading JPG colored image and saving image into raw or binary file using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to read a JPG image and want to save it in binary raw image file. Output should be in planar form, like first Red channel and so on.
This code I have made till now, but it is not working. Can you suggest me what should I do?

```
import cv2
H = 512;
W = 512;
size = H*W;

img = cv2.imread('f.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (H, W))
name = 'f'+str(H)+'x'+str(W)+'.bin'
f = open(name, 'w+b')
binary_format = bytearray(img)
f.write(binary_format)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Output dimensions
H, W = 512, 512

# Open image and resize to 512x512
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (H, W))

# Save as planar RGB output file
name = f'f-{H}x{W}.bin'
with open(name, 'w+b') as f:
    f.write(img[...,2].copy())     # write Red channel
    f.write(img[...,1].copy())     # write Green channel
    f.write(img[...,0].copy())     # write Blue channel
```

I put the `.copy()` in there to make the data contiguous for writing. I write channel 2 first, then 1 and then 0 because **OpenCV** stores images in `BGR` order and I presume you want the red plane first.

---

Note that you could do the above without needing any code using **ImageMagick** in the Terminal:

```
magick input.jpg -resize 512x512 -interlace plane -depth 8 RGB:data.bin
```

Change the `512x512` above to `512x512\!` if you are happy for the image to be distorted in aspect ratio to become the specified size.

And the reverse process of creating a JPEG from the binary, planar interleaved RGB data would be:

```
magick -size 512x512 -depth 8 -interlace plane RGB:data.bin reconstituted.jpg
```